# Is there any python way to detect service management system?

Tags: python, operating-system, systemd

There are quite a few service management system available: sysvinit, upstart, systemd etc.

Is there any python way to detect which is running in my operating system?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18209/detect-init-system-using-the-shell) on Unix SE and decide for yourself if it's worth the effort.